# 404 page not found in spring mvc example

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, dispatcher

I am developing spring application, I am getting 404 page not found.

next

my folder structure is like this.
WebContent-->WEB-INF-->jsp-->next.jsp

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.authority.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:Authority" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>



  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>

    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you calling the "next.jsp"?

Comment: In jsp page <a href="WEB-INF/jsp/next.jsp">next</a>

Comment: you can't do that. I say why in my answer.

Comment: You should add Controller method to return one of the views in /WEB-INF/jsp/

Comment: You should post the controller code that returns your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you use controllers?? normally pages from WEB-INF dir can't be displayed directly by invoking it from browser.

You should implement controller that will return "next", so it will be resolved to your jsp. Check [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) for more details

Comment: Should i need to implement controller for simple link also?

Comment: if you don't need special logic for that JSP, you should place your .jsp file somewhere else, e.g. WebContent-->next.jsp and then you can access it via url : /<your web app>/next.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Here is a quote from the Servlet Specification document that states that:

> Except for static resources and JSPs packaged in the METAINF/resources of a JAR file that resides in the WEB-INF/lib directory, no other 
>   files contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the 
>   container. However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code 
>   using the getResource and getResourceAsStream method calls on the 
>   ServletContext, and may be exposed using the RequestDispatcher calls.